# How to print out date and time in this format in Lua?

Tags: date, time, lua, formatting

I want to print out the date and time in this format like so

```
4/25/2017 12:45 PM
```

Comment: What do you use as input at what is your approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`os.date`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.date) has an optional first argument, `format`, which is used for formatting date and time. e.g.

```
print(os.date("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"))
-- 04/25/2017 04:39 PM
```

The detail of the format specifiers is in C's [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

Comment: This outputs `04/25/2017 12:45 PM`. Note the `0` in the month. There'll also be leading zeros the day, when appropriate.